# Application Version Selector implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, environment-variables

I have installed the following version of R in my windows 8 machine

```
•   R-3.0.0
•   R-3.0.1
•   R-.3.0.2
•   R-3.1.1
```

I need to create simple WPF application with ComboBox control to select the R versions
Based on the ComboBox selected Item, we have to add the directory of selected R version to the Environment variable. I have tried with using .txt file contains the information about R verion details and installed directory. But I can’t achieve my requirment. Is there any other way to achieve this?

I have use the XML file with the following code snippet and File Name is RVersion.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<RVersions>

  <RVersion>
    <Version>R-3.0.2</Version>
    <Path>C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin</Path>
  </RVersion>

  <RVersion>
    <Version>R-3.1.1</Version>
    <Path>C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin</Path>
  </RVersion>

</RVersions>
```

I have use the following code snippet in XAML file

```
<Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RData"
                         Source="F:\Big Data\Data Analytics\Layout\Layout\RVersion.xml"
                         XPath="RVersions/RVersion"/>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox             
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RData}}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="@Version"             
            Height="25"            
            SelectedIndex="0"  
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    </Grid>
```

In this case comboBox did not show the R Version details

Comment: Save the versions in a text or XML file, read them in to the application and populate an `ObservableCollection<string>` with them, then data bind that to a `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property. Add another `string` property to data bind to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property... job done. Why can't you do that?

Comment: i have use the following code snippet

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RVersions>
  <RVersion>
    <Version>R-3.0.2</Version>
    <Path>C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin</Path>
  </RVersion>

  <RVersion>
    <Version>R-3.1.1</Version>
    <Path>C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin</Path>
  </RVersion>
</RVersions>

Comment: <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RData"
                         Source="F:\Big Data\Data Analytics\Layout\Layout\RVersion.xml"
                         XPath="RVersions/RVersion"/>

    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RData}}" DisplayMemberPath="@Version" Height="25" SelectedIndex="0"  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>    </Grid>

Comment: but it did not show version name in combobox

Comment: Can I suggest adding that code into your question so that everybody can see it clearly? You might be more likely to get an answer then.

Comment: Did you set the `Window.DataContext`? If not, try adding `DataContext = this` into the end of the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60518/discussion-between-raja-sekar-and-sheridan).

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve this by using the following modified code snippet in DisplayMemberPath

```
<ComboBox             
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RData}}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Version"             
            Height="25"            
            SelectedIndex="0"  
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```